# Can't require goog.fx.Dragger in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript

I'm trying to build a small om-component that uses goog.fx.Dragger to make a target draggable. I require   goog.fx.Dragger :as dragger and like so:

```
(ns om-draggable-me.core
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [om.dom :as dom :include-macros true]
            [goog.fx.Dragger :as dragger]))
```

When i use it like:

```
(defn draggable [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IDidMount
    (did-mount [_]
               (let [target (om/get-node owner)]
                 (dragger. target)))
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
            (dom/div #js {:id "drag-box" :className "drag-box"}))))
```

I get the compiler warning:

WARNING: Use of undeclared Var om-draggable-me.core/dragger at line 22 src/cljs/om_draggable_me/core.cljs

Seen other examples of the use of goog.fx.DragDrop so why does not this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `require` form, `dragger` is a namespace alias

```
[goog.fx.Dragger :as dragger]
```

which is intended to be used like this:

```
dragger/your-var 
;; the same as goog.fx.Dragger/your-var
```

while in your script, it was used as if it's a var:

```
(dragger. target)
```

and, as the compiler complained, such var hasn't been defined.

You can see people refer to `clojure.string` like this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
```

without worrying about conflicting with `clojure.core/str` function:

```
(str/join ", " [1 2 3])
(str "hello" "world")
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Maybe better to use :import here instead `(:import [goog.fx Dragger])`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the alias did not work, it works with fully qualified name:

```
(did-mount [_]
           (let [target (om/get-node owner)]
             (goog.fx.Dragger. target)))
```